# Integral of a 2D function with parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, integral

I have a function in Matlab which takes four arguments:

```
function result = my_function(par1, x, y, par2)
// some code
end
```

I want to integrate it in 2D (along the x and y dimentions), for a chosen values of par1 and par2. Here is how I do it:

```
par1 = 1;par2 =2;
result = integral2(@(x,y)my_function(par1, x, y, par2), xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax);
```

However, when I ran this code and display the size of variables x and y inside my function, it is big. The integral2 function executes my function on arrays of arguments at once.

How can I force matlab to execute the function my_function for one value of x and y at a time?

Of course, I can check the size of x and y inside my function and then manually create an array of results:

```
function result = my_function(par1, x, y, par2)
result = zeros(size(x));
for i=1:size(result(:))
% do the work here
end
reshape(result, size(x))
end
```

But this isn't a very elegant solution.

Update: I agree that the integer is a scalar and I like it that way. The problem is that my function work only when the arguments (x and y) are scalars. 
Matlab needs an array of values of my function to calculate the integral, so it evaluates my function once when x and y are arrays. And I want it to evaluate my function many times for x and y which are scalars.

Comment: The integral *is*  a scalar. I'm not sure why you do not want one. You might want to loop over `par1` and `par2`, whatever they are, and store them, from within a loop, as `result(ii,jj)`, where `ii` is the loop over `par1` and `jj` the loop over `par2`

Comment: par1 and par2 are scalars, var1 and var 2 are the variables I integrate over. But it really doesn't matter. And I can do as you suggested, but it isn't an elegant solution. Matlab should be flexible enough to let me force the integral2 function to evaluate my function on scalar values.

Comment: What doesn't it do? And I didn't say anything about real or complex numbers - all my data is real. The problem is that the arguments should be scalars, not arrays. The domain is constant and isn't the problem.

Comment: How my par1 and par2 be xmin and x max? And why? I agree, I can't enter arrays in integral2 (and I'm not doing it). par1, par2, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax are all scalars. The only array that exists is the array created by integral2 using xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.

Comment: Oh, nvm, I missed that you put those into some function you are not showing us here. Still, I maintain that looping is your only solution here.

Comment: The function is "my_function" I described in my question. I didn't show its body, because it is not important and too long to post it.  Do  you mean looping inside "my_function"?